# Winforms Designer Error "An error occured while parsing EntityName"

Tags: c#, winforms, designer

I'am using a custom control code for my winforms application to create a custom colored progressbar. I can build it, and it works fine, BUT everytime I try to use designer, it crashes. "An error occured while parsing EntityName"

- If I add from the toolbox, [this is what I get](http://img188.imageshack.us/f/43680242.jpg/).
- If I insert a progressbar, then rewerite the code for my control (replace `progressBar` with `progressBarEx`), then [this is what I get](http://img843.imageshack.us/f/47990282.jpg/).

The code:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Crystal
{
public class ProgressBarEx : ProgressBar
{
    private SolidBrush brush = null;

    public ProgressBarEx()
    {
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (brush == null || brush.Color != this.ForeColor)
            brush = new SolidBrush(this.ForeColor);

        Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height);
        if (ProgressBarRenderer.IsSupported)
            ProgressBarRenderer.DrawHorizontalBar(e.Graphics, rec);
        rec.Width = (int)(rec.Width * ((double)Value / Maximum)) - 4;
        rec.Height = rec.Height - 4;
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, 2, 2, rec.Width, rec.Height);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding the solution and then opening the designer?

Comment: Yes, several times, deleted bin folder, close, reopened sln. Also searched for '&' symbols, as I googled for this problem on google, and someone said it caused by this character, but I didnt found any.

Comment: It is bombing when trying to read XML, what's the heck is that all about?  You haven't provided all the code, at least the Value and Maximum properties are missing.  What else is there?  Is it using any application settings?

Comment: Umm I dont know whats that xml reading thing, I dont even use any XML in my program. I dont know what that :O min and max value automatically created when I insert my control via toolbox. Because its a child class of progressbar, It has all properties, like the normal progressbar, so it has min and max values. This is me whole code for this custom progressbar. No app settings.

Comment: Form resources are in xml format, maybe there is something wrong?

Comment: I will take a look at it, but then whats the link between the progressbars? Designer is fine, If I dont use my custom progressbar.

Comment: I got this error, and it was because the Visual Studio Solution was checked out into a folder that contained the `&` character!   Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: Why don't you post the solution as an answer and set them to resolved? Otherwise users like me searches for open answers and found already solved answers... This corrupts the system.

Comment: @70sCommander: fully agreed. I've begun moving answers-in-questions into separate answers, especially when there has been no response to a comment like yours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sup>Dominik aka galaris provided his answer in his own question. I cleaned it up and moved it here:</sup>

The solution can be [found here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/5884c3db-63d3-44ca-a6b3-3dde6d361f1d). The problem is that one of my folders **contained a `&` character**. Moving the project to the desktop folder solved the problem.